# how is padding beneficial?

Tags: c, structure, padding

```
struct MixedData
{
    char Data1;
    short Data2;
    short Data3;
    double Data4;
    int Data5;
    double Data6;
};
```

The above `struct` will be automatically 'padded'. But I do not understand  how 'padding' is beneficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because most platforms suffer a performance penalty when reading unaligned data. For example, a 64 bit wide memory controller can read a `double` in one "cycle" as long as it is aligned properly, if not, it will take 2 cycles to read it and load the MC unnecessarily. Some platforms cannot even read unaligned data. That is why padding is a must to ensure everything is aligned optimally.

Comment: But I want to know that why most platforms suffer a performance penalty when reading unaligned data. Also as you have written  `a 64 bit wide memory controller can read a double in one "cycle" as long as it is aligned properly, if not, it will take 2 cycles to read it and load the MC unnecessarily` , why this is happening?

Comment: @kevingomes - because the MC itself can access memory addresses multiple of its width. For example, the 64 bit MC can read from address 0, 64, 128 and so on. If you have your 64 bit data aligned on a 64bit boundary, the MC will read all 64 bits in one swoop, if not aligned, the memory controller will read one 64 bit chunk, extract the data from it, read the next chunk to extract the rest of the data, and likely perform shifting and masking operations to combine the two chunks into a single 64 bit data type.

Comment: what does `64 bit boundary` means?

Comment: That means the address if a multiple of 8 bytes, e.g. 64 bits. The reason I used bytes is because the byte is the smallest addressable unit, if you want a single bit, you must address that byte and extract the bit from there.

Comment: BTW that is why MCs "overload" when you read a lot of bytes, because when reading a byte, the MC works at 1/8 of its capacity, but takes the same time it would need to read/write 8 bytes.

Comment: If I print the address of every element in my question then one address is got is `2686706` , but it is not a multiple of 8.

Comment: What data type is it?

Comment: @tangrs : `short data2` in my question?

Comment: @kevingomes - `short` is only 2 bytes, so it is a aligned at multiple of 2. Check the `double` alignment instead.

Comment: @ddriver : means that the address should be a multiple of the size of that particular data type.

Comment: Pretty much yes. And in the case of a struct (or class), padding is often added in the end to ensure that in an array of structs, the first member of the second struct is aligned properly.

Comment: @ddriver : added in the end of what?

Comment: @kevingomes - the end of the struct. For example a `struct {float, char}` will add 3 more bytes to the struct. So that the size of the struct will be  8 bytes instead of the 5 bytes which is the size of the user defined members.

Comment: @ddriver : does after padding, the structure elements are considered to be at contiguous memory locations?

Comment: @kevingomes - what do you mean by "contiguous memory locations"? The way you have declared the struct there will be a gap and padding between the first and second member. If you rearrange the elements to be double, double, int, short, short, char, then padding will only be added at the end, the size will not change, but where padding is inserted will change.

Answer (score 4):

On some CPU architectures, trying to load a word from an unaligned memory address can take many CPU cycles, while loading a word from an aligned address will take few CPU cycles. Some CPU architectures even *can't* load from unaligned addresses.

The compiler is helpful enough to try and place structure member variables on optimal positions for the CPU.

Comment: what does a `cycle` refers to?

Comment: @kevingomes - if your CPU runs at 2 GHz that means it runs at 2 billion cycles per second, that is a cycle.

Comment: And why unaligned memory takes more cycles?

Answer (score 4):

Some computers (e.g. RISC, and at one time ARM-based) can only access, say, a `double` only at specific memory boundaries. Other computers, such as 8086-based family, can do arbitrary accesses, but have a performance penalty.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on the answers already given with a visual representation.

When a word is aligned in memory, it looks like this, and only requires one reading.

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX | 12 34 56 78 90 ab cd ef |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
                           ^-----------------------^
                                     Cycle 1
```

When it's unaligned, some architectures require two cycles to fetch the word since it can't read past a boundary at a time or that memory addresses are internally represented as multiples of the word size. They need to fetch twice the amount of data, discard the useless parts and combine the useful parts to form the word.

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| XX XX XX XX XX 12 34 56 | 78 90 ab cd ef XX XX XX |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
                ^--------^ ^--------------^
                  Cycle 1      Cycle 2
```

Comment: In many cases, the situation is worse than you describe for a couple reasons: (1) Some processors don't have the ability to subdivide memory accesses.  An attempt to read a 32-bit value from an address which isn't a multiple of four will simply crash.  (2) Hardware is generally only capable of accessing data in chunks with power-of-two sizes.  For a processor to store an int64 to address 3 would require writing one byte to address 3, four to address 4, two to address 8, and one address 12.  The penalty for an unaligned access is thus not one cycle, but three.